# How to import the FBConnect folder in my iPhone project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, directory-structure

I am building an iPhone app that will include the FBConnect project to allow users to post data from the app to their wall on Facebook.  I'm having problems compiling my code right now because the project is unable to find my FBConnect directory, which is causing me to have about 150 compilation errors.

In my project, I have the Facebook sdk in a directory called, "src".  The name of my project is "MyProjectFolder", and I have moved the "src" directory, directly inside the "MyProjectFolder" directory, such that it is a sibling folder to: "build", and "Classes".  In XCode, I go to "Project Menu" -> "Edit project settings" and scroll down to “User Header Search Path” and add the entry, "../../src".  I also tried changing this to "../src".

Unfortunately, neither path appears to be working. Am I doing something wrong?  How do I include the Facebook sdk project folder inside my app directory, and call it in XCode?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my own problem.  Ironically, it was already answered on www.stackoverflow.com .  They are found here:

[Adding Facebook Connect to my iPhone Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382964/adding-facebook-connect-to-my-iphone-project)

["FBConnect/FBConnect.h" no such file or directory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165947/fbconnect-fbconnect-h-no-such-file-or-directory-error)

By following the instructions found above, I was able to solve my own issues.